# How to add an eventListener to each id of an array?

Tags: javascript

What I want is to add an eventListener to each id that I have, something like this:

```
var butn = [document.getElementById("b1"), document.getElementById("b2"), document.getElementById("b3"),
        document.getElementById("b4"), document.getElementById("b5"), document.getElementById("b6"),
        document.getElementById("b7"), document.getElementById("b8"), document.getElementById("b9")]

        butn.addEventListener("click", doSet)
```

How can I do that without using to much code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var ids = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5'];
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById(ids[i]).addEventListener("click", doSet);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since all your ids seem to start with `'b'`:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) 
  document.getElementById('b' + i).addEventListener("click", doSet);
```